# Unable to find children of div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I am trying to turn off an image for the first element in each faqs div class in HTML. I am trying to select the faqs parent element and then query down to find the first list element as in the javascript below:

```
$(function () {
    _faqs = $('.faqs').accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        selectedClass: 'open',
        animated: "slide",
        header: "dt"
    });

    console.log(_faqs.length); // returns 2, so it is selecting all faqs classes

    for (var i = 0; i < _faqs.length; i++) {
        _faqs[i].children('.corner.tr').first().hide();
        _faqs[i].children('.corner.tl').first().hide();

        // also tried using find()
        //_faqs[i].find('.corner.tr').first().hide();
        //_faqs[i].find('.corner.tl').first().hide();
    }
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="faqs">
        <dl class="thefaq">

                    <div class="corner tl">
                        <img src="bg-table-tl.gif" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="corner tr">
                        <img src="bg-table-tr.gif" alt="" />
                    </div>

                    <dt>
                        Question
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="open cf">
                        <p>Answer. <br />
                    </dd>
        </dl>
<br />
</div>
<div class="faqs">
        <dl class="thefaq">

                    <div class="corner tl">
                        <img src="bg-table-tl.gif" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="corner tr">
                        <img src="bg-table-tr.gif" alt="" />
                    </div>

                    <dt>
                        Question
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="open cf">
                        <p>Answer. <br />
                    </dd>
        </dl>
<br />
</div>
```

I keep getting a `Uncaught TypeError : object is not a function` error displayed in the developer tools console, what am I doing wrong here?

I have inspected the `_faqs` variable and it seems to contain methods for children yet I continue to get this error...

Comment: Use `$.each` function instead of `for` loop to traverse `jquery object`http://jsfiddle.net/mz7zmzyb/

Comment: console log.. what  _faqs[i] is showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$(".faqs").find(".corner.tr:first,.corner.tl:first").hide();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/mopjLn7p/34/)

Comment: that worked perfectly! thank you so much!! The demo was particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop `_faqs[i]` points to an `HTMLElement` which has a property called `children`, which is clearly not a function.

What you're trying to do is to call the `children()` method of jQuery. You can't call jquery methods on native `DOM` elements: for that you need to wrap the element in jQuery like `$(_faqs[i])`

```
$(_faqs[i]).children('.corner.tl').first().hide();
```

Comment: upvoted for explanation of why my solution was not working :)